# sql query return wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql

Why this query returns results where companyVisible is 0, even I am asking only for companies where companyVisible has value of 1?

```
SELECT c.companyID, c.companyDescription , c.companyName ,c.copmanyDrastiriotita, c.companyVisible
FROM company c
WHERE c.companyVisible = 1
AND c.companyDescription LIKE '%Keyword%'
OR c.companyName LIKE '%Keyword%'
OR c.copmanyDrastiriotita LIKE '%Keyword%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of OR clause

Apply brackets around `AND ...OR` clause

Use this

```
SELECT c.companyID, c.companyDescription , c.companyName ,c.copmanyDrastiriotita, c.companyVisible
FROM company c
WHERE c.companyVisible = 1
AND (c.companyDescription LIKE '%Keyword%'
OR c.companyName LIKE '%Keyword%'
OR c.copmanyDrastiriotita LIKE '%Keyword%')
```

Answer (score 2):

`AND` goes before `OR`, so you need to add parentheses.

```
SELECT c.companyID, c.companyDescription , c.companyName ,c.copmanyDrastiriotita, c.companyVisible
FROM company c
WHERE c.companyVisible = 1
AND (c.companyDescription LIKE '%Keyword%'
     OR c.companyName LIKE '%Keyword%'
     OR c.copmanyDrastiriotita LIKE '%Keyword%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using disjunctive normal form:

```
SELECT c.companyID,
       c.companyDescription, c.companyName, c.copmanyDrastiriotita,
       c.companyVisible
  FROM company c
 WHERE ( c.companyVisible = 1 AND c.companyName LIKE '%Keyword%' )
       OR ( c.companyVisible = 1 AND c.companyDescription LIKE '%Keyword%' )
       OR ( c.companyVisible = 1 AND c.copmanyDrastiriotita LIKE '%Keyword%' )
```

Using primitive operators (`c3` could be a `VIEW`):

```
SELECT c2.companyID,
       c2.companyDescription, c2.companyName, c2.copmanyDrastiriotita,
       c2.companyVisible
  FROM company c2, (
                    SELECT c1.companyID, c1.companyName AS text_to_search
                      FROM company c1
                    UNION
                    SELECT c.companyID, c.companyDescription AS text_to_search
                      FROM company c1
                    UNION
                    SELECT c1.companyID, c1.copmanyDrastiriotita AS text_to_search
                      FROM company c1
                   ) AS c3 ( companyID, text_to_search )
 WHERE c2.companyVisible = 1
       AND c3.text_to_search LIKE '%Keyword%'
```